# Determining if a Firefox extension is a "bootstrap" extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to get one of my Firefox 'legacy' extensions ported over to Pale Moon.  The extension backs up and restores extensions (among other browser components).  I'm having issues with trying to restore (install) any "bootstrap" extensions.  I need to be able to determine if a particular extension is "bootstrapped" or not before attempting the restore.

"Bootstrap" extensions have the line `<em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>` in their install.rdf file.  I could parse install.rdf to look for this line, but it is a very messy process to accomplish.  I would first have to un-pack the extension (.xpi), open install.rdf and look for the line - all programmatically.  While this can be done, it's not very practical or efficient.

Is there an XPCOM api that would tell me if the extension is bootstrapped or not?  I've looked at Mozilla's *AddonManager* component, but don't see anything that would help.  There is the *AddonManager.getInstallForFile()* method but it doesn't provide that information.

Comment: Not an XPCOM API answer (sorry), but does anything in the [CRX Viewer](https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer) area help? Consider, for example, https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/?crx=https%3A%2F%2Fca-archive.biz.tm%2Fstorage%2F2%2F2109%2Ffebe-8.9.3.1-fx.xpi%3Forigin%3Dcaa